# How to create a navigationBar programmatically with Swift?

Tags: swift, navigationbar

On my main view controller the navigation bar was created using the storyboard. I would like to create programmatically a navigation bar on the second view controller too  however I must do something wrong because it doesn't appear.

I call the second VC using this line of code:

```
@IBAction func showRecentSearch(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToRecentSearchVC", sender: self)
}
```

This is the second VC's code:

```
import UIKit

class RecentSearchTVC: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.delegate = self
        
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Test"
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
    }
}
```

The second VC is just a white screen.

Comment: Why not create the second VC's nav bar in the storyboard too?

Answer (score 0):

If your initial view controller is embedded in an `UINavigationController`, then you must check the 'Kind' property of the "goToRecentSearchVC" seque. It must be set to 'Show (e.g. Push)' in the interface designer.

If your initial view is **not** embedded in a navigation controller, then add an `UINavigationController` to your Storyboard, delete the default generated child view controller, and replace it with your current first view controller. You do this by dragging a outlet connection with your mouse from navigation controller to your view controller while pressing the Control key on your keyboard. When you end dragging, choose 'root view controller' from the Segue destination popup. When done, recheck the first part of my answer.